# Python/GDAL get unique values in discrete-valued raster

Tags: python, gdal, attribute-table

I would like to get some advice on the most efficient way to return a list of unique values of a discrete-valued raster using Python and GDAL.

I had thought that the most obvious way would be to examine the raster's attribute table, but if I do `band.GetDefaultRAT()` on the band of a raster dataset that contains an attribute table (the table is visible in ArcCatalog, anyway), the result is always `None`:

```
>>> rat = band.GetDefaultRAT()
>>> rat == None
True
```

In that case, I end up having to scan through each cell of the raster and build a list of unique values manually. Is this the only way to do it?

Or is there a way to build an attribute table with Python and GDAL, then query it for a list of unique values?

Comment: Which version of GDAL are you using btw?

Comment: stupid question but what is RAT?

Comment: RAT stands for Raster Attribute Table.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can use [np.unique](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) function from numpy lib:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

ds = gdal.Open("myimg.ext")
band =  ds.GetRasterBand(1)
array = np.array(band.ReadAsArray())
values = np.unique(array)
```

or you can one-shot it:

```
values = np.unique(np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()))
```

Comment: Why wrap `band.ReadAsArray()` in a `np.array` call? Doesn't it already return a numpy array?

Comment: Yes it does. Wrapping it in a np.array has no performance drawbacks, as it is not a copy but it uses the same memory address and helps your IDE identify the object so you'll have auto-completion enabled.