# Read RAT (raster attribute table) using GDAL or other python libraries?

Tags: python, gdal, raster-attribute-table

Referring to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33388/python-gdal-get-unique-values-in-discrete-valued-raster) post, is there any update on the reason why GDAL function `band.GetDefaultRAT()` always returns `NoneType`? I can't find much documentation.

I've tried to create a RAT for testing (using code from [here](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/563)), nonetheless if I then try to read the RAT using  `band.GetDefaultRAT()` I get `NoneType`, altough the RAT is surely there (I can see it in as xml and using gdalinfo or ArcCatalog). Is there anything I am missing?

I am running from Jupyter Notebook using conda (4.7.11) environment in Anaconda installed on Windows 10 OS, GDAL 2.3.3, released 2018/12/14

```
# create a RAT for testing
import os
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


fn = 'foo.tif'
ds = gdal.Open(fn, gdal.GA_Update)
rb = ds.GetRasterBand(1)

# Get unique values in the band
u = np.unique(rb.ReadAsArray())

# Create a random field as well
r = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=u.size)

# Create and populate the RAT
rat = gdal.RasterAttributeTable()
rat.CreateColumn('VALUE', gdal.GFT_Integer, gdal.GFU_Generic)
rat.CreateColumn('RANDOM', gdal.GFT_Integer, gdal.GFU_Generic)
for i in range(u.size):
    rat.SetValueAsInt(i, 0, int(u[i]))
    rat.SetValueAsInt(i, 1, int(r[i]))

# Associate with the band
ds.FlushCache()
rb.SetDefaultRAT(rat)

# Close the dataset and delete variables
ds = None
rat = None
rb = None

# try to read the RAT

ds = gdal.Open(fn)
rb = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
rat=ds.GetRasterBand(1).GetDefaultRAT()
print(type(rat))
```

RETURNS:

`<class 'NoneType'>`

Output of gdalinfo -stat foot.tif where RAT is visible

`PS D:\Dev\Jupiter\notebooks\data> gdalinfo -stats foo.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: foo.tif
       foo.tif.aux.xml
Size is 538, 233
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (5.970019531250017,47.775634765625000)
Pixel Size = (0.008335632551115,-0.008350238063305)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   5.9700195,  47.7756348) (  5d58'12.07"E, 47d46'32.29"N)
Lower Left  (   5.9700195,  45.8300293) (  5d58'12.07"E, 45d49'48.11"N)
Upper Right (  10.4545898,  47.7756348) ( 10d27'16.52"E, 47d46'32.29"N)
Lower Right (  10.4545898,  45.8300293) ( 10d27'16.52"E, 45d49'48.11"N)
Center      (   8.2123047,  46.8028320) (  8d12'44.30"E, 46d48'10.20"N)
Band 1 Block=538x15 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=1.000 Max=5.000
  Minimum=1.000, Maximum=5.000, Mean=2.342, StdDev=1.332
  NoData Value=0
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=5
    STATISTICS_MEAN=2.3424814343154
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=1.3315515074732
<GDALRasterAttributeTable>
  <FieldDefn index="0">
    <Name>VALUE</Name>
    <Type>0</Type>
    <Usage>0</Usage>
  </FieldDefn>
  <FieldDefn index="1">
    <Name>RANDOM</Name>
    <Type>0</Type>
    <Usage>0</Usage>
  </FieldDefn>
  <Row index="0">
    <F>0</F>
    <F>636</F>
  </Row>
  <Row index="1">
    <F>1</F>
    <F>205</F>
  </Row>
  <Row index="2">
    <F>2</F>
    <F>552</F>
  </Row>
  <Row index="3">
    <F>3</F>
    <F>33</F>
  </Row>
  <Row index="4">
    <F>4</F>
    <F>308</F>
  </Row>
  <Row index="5">
    <F>5</F>
    <F>742</F>
  </Row>
</GDALRasterAttributeTable>`

Comment: This is the GDAL RAT test from the autotest suite https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gcore/rat.py.

Comment: thank you user30184, although I am not quite sure how to use it (I am still a python beginner); can you point to any further instructions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are opening the raster in read-only mode.

```
rs = gdal.Open(fn)
```

Open it in update mode instead.

```
rs = gdal.Open(fn, gdal.GA_Update)
```

With this change your code works in gdal 2.4. However, it does not work for me with gdal 2.2 and 2.3.  This *may* be a result of [this commit](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/e53f94dbbebc0f725280dcd2c696eb3db7856816) which appears to fix GeoTIFF `GetDefaultRAT()` in gdal 2.4 and 3.0.

Comment: Unfortunately I did change the code according to your suggestion, but I still get `NoneType` as output. Anyhow good to learn about the mode option.

Comment: @dorakiara it works for me, the 2nd script prints `<class 'osgeo.gdal.RasterAttributeTable'>`. Can you edit your question and add more info, inc. output of `gdalinfo -stats foo.tif` and `gdalinfo --version` and some details on your system (OS, how you installed GDAL)

Comment: I have edited the question adding some system info and gdal output. Also it is now a single test snippet where I first delete variables and then try to read back the RAT. Still getting `NoneType` though. Interesting that it works for you, which are your system setting if I may ask?

Comment: @dorakiara install gdal>=2.4 from conda forge. `conda install -c conda-forge 'gdal>=2.4'` (you may need to change the single quotes to double quotes, can't remember windows cmd usage).

Comment: Thank you @user2856! Indeed once I finally managed to upgrade to gdal>= 2.4 the code worked. made my day!