# Can GeoTIFFs hold metadata on class labels?

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, rasterio, metadata

I am creating GeoTIFFs in Python using `rasterio` and recently discovered that you can set band descriptions like so:

```
with rio.open(out_tif, 'w', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(data)
    dst.descriptions(['classification', 'ndvi', 'conf_intervals'])
```

where here I am creating a 3-band image with names `classification`, `ndvi` and `conf_intervals`. These names then show up when I open the .tif in QGIS, for example.

I was wondering if it was possible to list the class values for the `classification` band? For instance:

```
1: Deciduous
2. Developed
3. Barren
4. Shrub
```

I found [this GDAL page](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html) listing the GeoTIFF metadata options, but the information is a little inscrutable to me. Possibly the `GEO_METADATA` tag is what I want, but I can't find any information on it. Any insight on this?

Comment: I found that you can add arbitrary key: value metadata to the .tif with `dst.update_tags(key=value)` which might be as close as we can get, but they won't get assigned to a specific band

Comment: I know that GDAL supports raster attribute tables https://gdal.org/doxygen/classGDALRasterAttributeTable.html#details but I am not sure how to use then with GeoTIFF. However, it seems to be possible https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333897/read-rat-raster-attribute-table-using-gdal-or-other-python-libraries.